# An alternative for ‘in whatever way’ in this context

Tags: phrase-requests

> The problem X can be explained in different ways.
>
> The problem X, **explained in whatever way**, has an implication for
> our situation.

The bolder part is meant to mean ‘regardless of how we explain it’. I am looking to say that in another way, using maybe a more fitting, more common phrase in that sense. The verb ‘explained’ is not crucial. It can be replaced by some other verbs. For example,

> This term, **interpreted in whatever way**, is not applicable here.
> This
> rule, **construed in whatever way**, is not fair.

I know that I have seen at least one other way to say such a thing, but I cannot remember. I know that we can say ‘regardless of how we explain it’ or ‘regardless of how it is explained’ or ‘no matter how it is explained’. But I am looking for a shorter phrase.

Comment: for what it's worth, before I even got to the end of your question I already was thinking "regardless of how it's explained," so I would imagine that is the most obvious/understandable/idiomatic way to say it.

Comment: No matter how it is explained, the problem X has an implication for our situation.

Comment: No matter ... seems to me to be the most idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

- This term,  *whatever its explanation*, has an implication for our situation. (*short*)
- This term, *however explained*, has an implication for our situation. (*shortest*)
- This term, *however construed/interpreted/conceived/justified…*, has an implication for our situation.

([ref. 1848](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_American_Journal_of_the_Medical_Scie/qO1GAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22however+explained%22&pg=PA540&printsec=frontcover)) The author of the present paper is not disposed to add to these hypotheses; but observes that, however explained, the diminution of the number of the pulse is, in some measure, the index of the beneficial effort of the remedy.

([ref. 1948](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_Modern_Theatre/cMcHAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22however+explained%22&dq=%22however+explained%22&printsec=frontcover)) But, however explained or explained away, the Broadway play is supposed to be interesting in print and is read in the provinces by many who will never see it staged. In short, the fact that a play is printed is sufficient warrant for ...

([ref. 1960](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/New_Times/Z2OEvxAnbVwC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22however+explained%22&dq=%22however+explained%22&printsec=frontcover)) And, to be sure, such currency depreciation, however explained, is only a form of masked inflation.